# script to copy and paste file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to complete a copy a few hundred files and copy from source file with many directories into a new file. I have a spreadsheet with the filename and their paths, so I have concatenated that list into a text file named: file-list.txt.  I want the script to search the S/drive for the provided file path in the text file, then copy it to the destination folder

I found the script below, but I can not make it work for my purposes:

```batch
echo off
set src_folder=S:\data\010\Files
set dst_folder=C:\Users\Desktop\test
for(/f "tokens=*" %%i in file-list.txt do (
    xcopy /s/e/u "%src_foler%\%%i" "dest_folder%"))
```

An example of the files in the file-list.txt is:

```
\leaserecords1\SL0000NQ\LD00GN21.pdf
\leaserecords1\SL0000NZ\LD00I4QX.pdf
\leaserecords1\SL00001F\LD003CQ9.TIF
```

Comment: I am struggling to understand what you require, and does this have to be in batch, or can it be written in PowerShell? Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how to ask well structured questions.

Comment: I am sorry for my lack of clarification. this is my first post.  usually I can find what i need with just a google search.  I am trying to get it done in PowerShell and have been given a tight deadline

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you. What have you tried so far? What result did you expect? What didn't work the way you wanted? I would expect copying files to be in about every PowerShell tutorial in the world.

Comment: when trying to execute the provided powershell script i get an error of a "missing statement body in for loop"

Comment: The provided script is written in batch, not PowerShell, and its [syntax](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754900.aspx) is incorrect on top of that.

Comment: please forgive my Ignorance.

Comment: `%src_foler%` contains a spelling mistake ...

Answer (score 0):

Assumption based on your provided script.

```bat
echo off
set "src_folder=S:\data\010\Files"
set "dst_folder=%UserProfile%\Desktop\test"
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (file-list.txt) do (
    xcopy /s/u "%src_folder%%%i" "%dst_folder%"
)
```

Comment: to show my ignorance, I was informed that was a batch script and would not work in powershell. I tried that and ran into errors with open and close () as well as "missing statement body in for loop"

Comment: That's correct, the question as answered does no longer mention powershell and neither does it any longer carry the powershell tag. I have hopefully fixed your batch file.